# Python plotting with matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

At the moment I am desperately trying to solve following task:

Given a "test.csv" with following content

```
name1;0.01923037196457715
name2;-0.5563708550161747
name3;-0.0021840865080922593
...
```

So you have a name and a corresponding float value per row.
I want to plot a horizontal bar chart, with the names on the y axis and the coresponding values on the x axis.
It has to be sorted descending by the value.
Also I want to convert each negative value to a positive and put "(-)" string  after the corresponding name and a "(+)" string for positive values after corresponding name.

So far I have tried the following:

```
    features = []
    pcc = []

    with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        for row in csv_reader:
            features.append(row[0])
            pcc.append(row[1])
    """
    row = 0
    for f, c in zip(features, pcc):
        if c < 0:
            features[row] = f + "(-)"
            pcc[row] = c * -1
            row += 1
        else:
            features[row] = f + "(+)"
            row += 1
    """
    indices = np.argsort(pcc)

    plt.title('Correlation Coefficients per Feature')
    plt.barh(range(len(indices)), pcc[indices], color='b', align='center')
    plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), [features[i] for i in indices])
    plt.xlabel('Correlation Coefficient')
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('correlation_ranking.png')
```

The error I am stuck at the Moment goes as follows:

```
        plt.barh((len(indices)), pcc[indices], color='b', align='center')
        TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Can you help me achieve this? I am not familiar with Python.

Answer (score 0):

A better code will be like this:
1- Put your input in csv with column names, like this image [image]

2- Read the csv, sort by values, put columns in arrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("input/test.csv")
rows,cols = np.shape(df)   
#print ('Rows:{} Columns:{}'.format(rows, cols))  

#display(df)
df=df.sort_values(by=['Values']) # or , ascending=False

NamesArray=df.iloc[:, 0].values
ValuesArray=df.iloc[:, 1].values

#print ('NamesArray:{}'.format(NamesArray)) 
#print ('ValuesArray:{}'.format(ValuesArray))
```

3- Plot the horizontal bars

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y_pos = np.arange(len(NamesArray))
ax.barh(y_pos, ValuesArray,  align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(NamesArray)
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='lightsteelblue', linestyle='-')

ax.invert_yaxis() 
ax.set_xlabel('Values')
ax.set_title('Names')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you add ( , ascending=False) in the sort:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, doing it with panda Dataframe is a good idea. Still I need to implement the step where I turn negative values to positives and alter the names like I described, before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in the comment, add sign to the names and put values in absolute:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("input/test.csv")
rows,cols = np.shape(df)   
#print ('Rows:{} Columns:{}'.format(rows, cols))  

#display(df)
#df=df.sort_values(by=['Values'], ascending=False)
df=df.iloc[df['Values'].abs().argsort()].reset_index(drop=True)
#display(df)

NamesArray=df.iloc[:, 0].values
ValuesArray=df.iloc[:, 1].values

#print ('NamesArray:{}'.format(NamesArray)) 
#print ('ValuesArray:{}'.format(ValuesArray))

for i in range(len(NamesArray)):
    if ValuesArray[i] < 0:
       NamesArray[i]=NamesArray[i]+'-' 
    else:
       NamesArray[i]=NamesArray[i]+'+' 

ValuesArray=np.absolute(df.iloc[:, 1].values)
#print ('NamesArray:{}'.format(NamesArray)) 
#print ('ValuesArray:{}'.format(ValuesArray))
```

[image]